# Is it safe to create new .RDLC report as a copy of existing .RDLC report?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

Is it safe to create new .RDLC report as a copy of existing .RDLC report?

When I say "copy" I mean file copy/paste.

The reason I ask is that when you open .RDLC report as text you will see that it contains something that looks like unique report ID at the end of the file:

```
  <rd:ReportID>34154e6a-cb1b-483e-aa89-07fd8b77e73e</rd:ReportID>
```

So the concern is if I just copy the file it will have the same ReportID and I am not sure if it can present a potential problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an operation I do often with `.rdlc` file created in `VS` (Windows Forms, ASP.NET) and I've never encountered problems.

Comment: Have you done the same with .RDL files? I would be more concerned about them since they are published to the server to a sort of a shared storage (database table).

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side I generated a new GUID and pasted it in `ReportID`. I used https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx but there are plenty of other ways to do it.